# Why does my function not return the error string?

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

I have function below.  It does what it needs to except that it does not return  the error string I want.

It always returns "".

I've put breakpoints and seen it step into each error case, but it doesn't return there. It returns at the end of the function.

I'm lost, I'm sure I'm making a really stupid mistake but I don't get it...

Save me the few hairs I have please :)

```
    public validatePanel = () => {
        this.Queries().forEach(function(q, i) {

            if(q.from() == "" || q.from() == null || q.from() == undefined) {
                return "Please select a database";
            }

            if(q.select().length > 0) {
                q.select().forEach(function(s, j) {
                    if(s.selectoption() == "" || s.selectoption() == null || s.selectoption() == undefined){
                        return "Please select a stat to show";
                    }
                });
            }

            if(q.where().length > 0) {
                q.where().forEach(function(w, j) {
                    if(w.whereoption() == "" || w.whereoption() == null || w.whereoption() == undefined){
                        return "Please select a filter to filter on";
                    }

                    if(w.wherevalue() == "" || w.wherevalue() == null || w.wherevalue() == undefined) {
                        return "Please select a value for your filter";
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return "";
    }
```

Comment: you function has got the only return value = `""`
`.forEach` method does not return value for your `validatePanel` function.
Also it is not clear what `this.Queries` is

Comment: Ok color me stupid, but why not? and better yet how do i make it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Alex Bykov, your `forEach` function is not causing a return.

Your question on why not, per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

The return value of the function is undefined

> Return
>
> value undefined.

Which means nothing you can do will generate a return value you can use. Also per the MDN there is no way to stop or break the loop other than throwing an exception.

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
>   throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method
>   is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead. If you are testing the
>   array elements for a predicate and need a Boolean return value, you
>   can use every() or some() instead. If available, the new methods
>   find() or findIndex() can be used for early termination upon true
>   predicates as well.

Which means you will need to throw your exception in the `forEach` loop and then catch the exception and return the string like below 
(*unless you use a normal for loop then you can do whatever you please*)

```
try {
       this.Queries().forEach(function(q, i) {

            if(q.from() == "" || q.from() == null || q.from() == undefined) {
                throw "Please select a database";
            }

            if(q.select().length > 0) {
                q.select().forEach(function(s, j) {
                    if(s.selectoption() == "" || s.selectoption() == null || s.selectoption() == undefined){
                        throw "Please select a stat to show";
                    }
                });
            }

            if(q.where().length > 0) {
                q.where().forEach(function(w, j) {
                    if(w.whereoption() == "" || w.whereoption() == null || w.whereoption() == undefined){
                        throw "Please select a filter to filter on";
                    }

                    if(w.wherevalue() == "" || w.wherevalue() == null || w.wherevalue() == undefined) {
                        throw "Please select a value for your filter";
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
catch(err) {
console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: That works like a charm but seems Incredibly hackish... i guess i could go with for loops.

Comment: @Puzzle84 i would suggest the for loop myself, I understand why it is that way. But sometimes that is the way the cookie crumblies

Comment: @Puzzle84 You can go for array.some function instead of forEach if you want to break loop rather than going the for loop.